# Determining a point on a plane given a normal and a vector that passes through a point

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm really stuck on determining the constraints of this question in part 2.

Part one states:

```
Throughout this question P will be the plane in R^3 that passes
through the origin and is normal to the vector n. Furthermore, p ∈ R^3 will be a
point that is not on P and L will be the line in R^3
that passes through the point p
and is in the direction some vector v.
```

Draw a schematic diagram to display the above.
The above I believe I can do

This is where I'm currently stuck:

```
Give a necessary and sufficient condition on n and v so that L intersects P
and find a formula in terms of n, p and v for this point of intersection.
```

I believe the above condition is that v can't be perpendicular to n. But struggle to find a formula to give the point of intersection.

Any help and links to further resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the plane and the line will intersect unless $n$ and $v$ are perpendicular. The line $L$ can be parameterised by
$$L: r_0=p+\lambda v$$
with the real parameter $\lambda$. Then the plane $P$ can be written as
$$P: r_1\cdot n=0$$
as the plane passes through the origin and all points on it are perpendicular to $n$ - so their dot product with $n$ is zero.

The line and plane intersect where the values of $r_0$ and $r_1$ are the same and hence
$$r_0\cdot n=0$$
$$(p+\lambda v)\cdot n=0$$
for some unique value of $\lambda$ which can then give the coordinate by using
$$L: r_0=p+\lambda v$$
Giving a coordinate of $p+\lambda v$ with $\lambda$ being the solution of $$(p+\lambda v)\cdot n=0$$

Comment: Just to clarify, P:r1⋅n=0 is only true for planes that pass through the origin? So the dot product of any point on a plane that doesn't pass through the origin and the vector normal to that plane is not 0 and so therefore this question wouldn't have a single solution or any solution at all? Many thanks for your clear and precise answer too.

Comment: If it did not pass through the origin, then this dot product would result in a constant equal to the position vector of any point $a$ in the plane dotted with the normal vector $n$. The intersection would then occur when $(p+\lambda v)\cdot n = a \cdot n$ instead.